# Update array from a different component

Tags: angular, typescript

I've just started out with Angular and I'm building a basic app.
Basically I have the main list view which gets a list from DB.
I have 2 components: list-view and then the form-overlay-view which is hidden unless the user clicks to add.

To add an item to the list the user clicks on a button which then shows a popup overlay (**the URL of the page stays** the same basically once the button is clicked the overlay becomes visible and the user can fill the info there and then click Add to add the new item to the DB. once the add btn is clicked the form overlay is hidden again and we see the list.

**The issue is in order to have the list updated and request the new data from the server I need to update the "Items:[]" which displays the list but I'm not sure how to access it from the form component as that Array is declared in the List-View-Comp. Shall I just put them all together in one component or is there a way I can access that array using the child component (form-view) and update it from there?

```
//*when btn is clicked the form becomes hidden and in 
here I want to update the array which is on the main-list-view component *//

  closeForm(){
    document.querySelector('.modal').classList.remove('is-active');
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use an Angular singleton service to hold the data: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: I solved this by using @output and event emitter so basically once the close form btn is being clicked I emit the event which then in my parent element calls the updateList function ... is that a good practice tho?